# Add the hreflang in link for each category

Tags: magento-1.8, seo, link, hreflang

i have using the same url for different languages.

```
<reference name="head">
   <action method="addLinkRel">
      <rel>alternatve</rel>
      <href>https://www.example.com/</href>
      <hreflang>x-default</hreflang>
   </action>
   <action method="addLinkRel">
      <rel>alternatve</rel>
      <href>https://www.example.com/</href>
      <hreflang>de</hreflang>
   </action>
   <action method="addLinkRel">
      <rel>alternatve</rel>
      <href>https://www.example.com/top.html</href>
      <hreflang>de-de</hreflang>
   </action>
   <action method="addLinkRel">
      <rel>alternatve</rel>
      <href>https://www.example.com/</href>
      <hreflang>de-at</hreflang>
   </action>
   <action method="addLinkRel">
      <rel>alternative</rel>
      <href>https://www.example.com/</href>
      <hreflang>de-ch</hreflang>
   </action>
</reference>
```

But while using this code in category->custom design in manage categories.
I'm geting only i url in the page. i check it in page source

```
<link rel="alternative" hreflang="de-ch" href="https://www.example.com/" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 <reference name="head">
        <block type="core/text" name="rel.hreflang">
            <action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<link rel="alternative" hreflang="x-default" href="https://www.example.com/" />]]></text></action>
            <action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<link rel="alternative" hreflang="de" href="https://www.example.com/" />]]></text></action>
            ...
        </block>
 </reference>
```

I think the issue have something to do with `$this->_data['items'][$type.'/'.$name]` evaluating to the same array key.

To debug take a look at `app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php`

```
/**
 * Add Link element to HEAD entity
 *
 * @param string $rel forward link types
 * @param string $href URI for linked resource
 * @return Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head
 */
public function addLinkRel($rel, $href)
{
    $this->addItem('link_rel', $href, 'rel="' . $rel . '"');
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Add HEAD Item
 *
 * Allowed types:
 *  - js
 *  - js_css
 *  - skin_js
 *  - skin_css
 *  - rss
 *
 * @param string $type
 * @param string $name
 * @param string $params
 * @param string $if
 * @param string $cond
 * @return Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head
 */
public function addItem($type, $name, $params=null, $if=null, $cond=null)
{
    if ($type==='skin_css' && empty($params)) {
        $params = 'media="all"';
    }
    $this->_data['items'][$type.'/'.$name] = array(
        'type'   => $type,
        'name'   => $name,
        'params' => $params,
        'if'     => $if,
        'cond'   => $cond,
   );
    return $this;
}
```